# Why was Merlin's action with the land mine needed?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-golden-circle

In *Kingsman: The Golden Circle*, In the scene where Merlin briefly freezes the landmine trigger, pushes Eggsy off, and holds down the trigger with his own foot instead, why didn't he just use a rock or something instead?

Comment: I was having same query my self. But I satisfy myself with the answer that they wan to dramatize the scene. No other reason.

Comment: Actually, I think it was an accident. Merlin was supposed to count to three, but Eggsy jumped too soon and Merlin stepped on the mine to keep it from going off. Doesn't make too much sense either as the trigger mechanism was supposed to be frozen. Why not just go ahead and run away?

Answer (score 4):

There is a certain amount of poetic license used in this scene.

Although it could be argued that the rock could have unexpectedly rolled off and killed them all. And perhaps there wasn't enough time to place a rock after Eggsy got off.

If you want to dissect landmine plotholes, many argue that landmines would simply go off as soon as pressure was applied to them, for effectiveness,  as discussed on [this TV Tropes article](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LandMineGoesClick).

Comment: I'm sure it's just going to be a poetic license answer really - LOVED the movie; this, however, was the main point that bugged me afterward; I'm wishing for a reasonable in-universe explanation. Given their insanely high skill level and that they had plenty of time to plan something, I'm certain they could have made a weight setup that would work (given the dubious explode on release mine setup)

Comment: Yeah this was my only gripe with the movie too! And I felt especially felt cheated considering it was Merlin's first mission :/

Comment: As for the trigger on release mines, I could go with 'Poppy wanted them like that, as per the Vietnam movies from the era she loves'.

Comment: if trigger-on-release landmines explode horizontally at head height to take out groups as per the reddit link, then maybe as hinted in some interviews there is a chance of Merlin being in K3 :)

Comment: It seemed like the goal was to trigger it when enough baddies were around (thus the singing). That distraction required the human operator I guess.

Comment: @Siddhartha: it was not Merlin's first mission - he was on the mission shown in the first scene of *Kingsman: The Secret Service* (and therefore probably others)